# MySQL join unknown column in field list - unsure why it is unknown

Tags: mysql, join

I'm struggling with the below query. I'm getting this error message...

## 1054 - Unknown column 'scout_report_descriptions.ball_retention' in 'field list'

however the column is there in the table scout_report_descriptions (below)

[image: table 2]

I am trying to join with this table (opp_team_scout_2)

[image]

To produce a table with the team_name column alongside a verbal comment for each attribute (based on the numerical rank)

The query is below...

SELECT opp_team_scout_2.team_name, scout_report_descriptions.`ball_retention`,
scout_report_descriptions.`ball_winning`, scout_report_descriptions.`pass_penetration`,etc

FROM opp_team_scout_2

```
LEFT JOIN scout_report_descriptions s1 ON s1.rank = opp_team_scout_2.`ball_retention`

LEFT JOIN scout_report_descriptions s2 ON s2.rank =opp_team_scout_2.`ball_winning`

LEFT JOIN scout_report_descriptions s3 ON s3.rank =opp_team_scout_2.`pass_penetration`etc
```

Comment: Please:  [Use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the aliases(s1,s2,s3) to reference the column names.

```
SELECT opp_team_scout_2.team_name, 
       s1.ball_retention, 
       s2.ball_winning, 
       s3.pass_penetration

FROM opp_team_scout_2    
LEFT JOIN scout_report_descriptions s1 ON s1.rank = opp_team_scout_2.`ball_retention`
LEFT JOIN scout_report_descriptions s2 ON s2.rank =opp_team_scout_2.`ball_winning`
LEFT JOIN scout_report_descriptions s3 ON s3.rank =opp_team_scout_2.`pass_penetration`etc
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers, explain why it answers the question. Please don't answer duplicates, vote to close, this is an obvious & easily found faq.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by putting aliases (s1, s2 etc) in field list at top of query.